# When to use 'java.util.Objects.*'?

Tags: java, oop, java-7

I was going through [Java 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7) features and they talked about [`java.util.Objects`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html) class.

What I am failing to understand is what is the functional difference betwee

```
java.util.Objects.toString(foo)
vs
foo == null ? "":foo.toString()
```

All I could see extra was a null check and functional notation instead of [OOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming) style.

What am I missing ?

Comment: Why does there have to be a functional difference? Isn't a clearer notation a benefit in itself?

Comment: The actual question is why this method was introduced given the fact that there was already `String.valueOf` since Java 1.0 which does exactly the same (`Objects.toString` simply calls it).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The main advantage of [`java.util.Objects.toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#toString-java.lang.Object-) is that you can easily use it on a return value that might be null, rather than needing to create a new local variable (or worse calling the function twice).

Compare

```
Foo f = getFoo();
String foo = (f==null) ? "null" : f.toString();
```

or the cringe-worthy and bug inducing

```
String foo = (getFoo()==null) ? "null" : getFoo().toString()
```

to the `Objects.toString` based version

```
String foo = Objects.toString(getFoo());
```

Answer (score 5):

Calling [`Objects.toString(foo)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#toString(java.lang.Object)) just removes the need for you to remember to do null checks, and means you can use it directly on a method return value (e.g. `Objects.toString(getPossibleNullObject())`) without storing it in a variable first (or calling the method twice).

Note however that the method actually returns:

> the result of calling `toString` for a non-null argument and `"null"` for a `null` argument

so it is actually equivalent to:

```
foo == null ? "null" : foo.toString();
```

if you want `""` for a null value you can use the overload that passes a `nullDefault` return value [`Objects.toString(foo, "")`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#toString(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.String))